# Filter Django objects where related object exists

Tags: django

This is bound to be a duplicate question but I can't find any others. I'm trying to get a list of photos that have complaints. I can't simply get complaints and deal with the related photos - I need a queryset of photos.

This should work but doesn't seem right:

```
Photo.objects.filter(complaint__id__gte=0)
```

This doesn't seem like the most efficient way:

```
Photo.objects.annotate(Count('complaint')).exclude(complaint__count=0)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

how about ...

`Photo.objects.filter(complaint__isnull=False)`

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: You might also need a .distinct() in the end to replicate the same as an annotate does. At least I did.

Comment: @Christoffer you saved my life, thanks. It is a deadly issue, so i want to write a comment and improve emphasis.

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure which variant is the best, but that works as well.

`Photo.objects.exclude(complaint=None)`

Generated SQL query is not exactly like in the case of `.filter(complaint__isnull=False)`, but sense is identical.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, because it doesn't require a `.distinct()` call to work with multi-valued relationships.

Comment: This answer also works when using `Q` objects. This code works: `Q(related_object=None)` whether this doesn't: `Q(related_object__is_null=True)`

Comment: this is shorter but also slower.

Comment: @ezdookie I tested it locally (50 k rows), speed is almost the same, the difference is about 5%.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of the relationship and filter logic you might need this *(or this can turn out to be more readable)*:

```py
complaints = Complaint.objects.filter(
    # some complex filter here
   Q(...) & Q(...) | Q(...)
)

Photo.objects.annotate(
    has_complaints=Exists(complaints)
).filter(has_complaints=True)
```