# Filter queryset by reverse exists check in Django

Tags: python, django

I have models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_comments')
```

And a queryset which is filtered by query params:

```py
user = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('user_id', None)
active = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('active', None)
has_comments = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('has_comments', None)

qs = Post.objects.all()

if user:
    qs = qs.filter(user=user)
if active:
    qs = qs.filter(active=active)
if has_comments:
    ???
```

I don't get how I can filter this query while maintaining all the previous filters. Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/):

> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829082/filter-django-objects-where-related-object-exists) it follows your code would be:

```
if user:
    qs = qs.filter(user=user)
if active:
    qs = qs.filter(active=active)
if has_comments:
    qs = qs.filter(comment__isnull=False)
```

With regards to performance take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437609/4850343) into account:

> Django doesn't support the select_related() method for reverse foreign
>   key lookups, so the best you can do without leaving Python is two
>   database queries.

You should also have a look at [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which can, unlike [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) do lookups across reverse `ForeignKeys`, albeit with a separate query for each element of the queryset.

Comment: Thanks! ```qs.filter(post_comments__isnull=False)``` has worked. A little more explanation about this in the documentation would've been nice.

Comment: Note that my blog entry is pretty outdated, prefetch_related hadn't been added when I wrote that and it does pretty much what I say there.

Answer (score 0):

The query you want is:

```
qs.filter(post_comments__isnull=False).distinct()
```

`__isnull=False` on a reverse relationship allows you to filter the join for rows where a post_comment is present.  However, this will give you duplicate results for each post_comment, so you need `.distinct()` to dedupe.