# How do I find only objects that have a related object in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to figure out the best way to get only the questions that have at least one answer. (I don't need to know how many.)

I have the following model.

```
class ChallengeQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    """Basic forum thread of questions and answers"""
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    original_question = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='answers')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text_data = models.TextField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_data
```

I can get the current list of all parent questions easy enough with this query:

```
questions = (
        PublicChallengeQuestionAnswer.objects
        .filter(challenge=challenge, original_question__isnull=True, answers__isnull=True, marked_hidden=False)
        .order_by('-creation_date')
        .all()
    )
```

Is there a simple way to modify this query by adding to it a filter that removes all questions that don't have answers?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077469/856070

Comment: add `answers__isnull=False` OR `exclude(answers__isnull=True)`

Comment: @jcfollower link is exact. We can mark this as Duplicate

Comment: Thanks you all! This was the solution, though I never found that post.